# Session handling and signing in/out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, authentication

I'm developing Rails application and I have to use authentication. I installed devise gem and trying to get used to it. Anyway - I have 2 problems, which may be connected (don't know it)

1. When signing in, how to sign out user, that is already signed in as the same user? I mean - From machine M1 someone signed in, next from machine M2, the other user is signing in. I want to sign out user from M1
2. How to store data information in session? I will have 3 forms, some dependent to other, and only after last one I need to create entry in database. I wanted to store other information in session. How to do it, or is it bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) this routes ends the session with devise

```
destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)                  {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
```

just add a link pointing to "/users/sign_out" and it will sign out the user. I dont follow the part about user in M1 and M2 but you can sign out all users at once with sign_out_all_scopes

2) session[:anything] = 'value_you_want' will store information in the session, remember that by default session store is set in a coockie so you only have 40k to store data.

If you want to make a wizard like form i recommend going to www.railscasts.com and search for "wizard", there is a screencast there of how to achieve what you want.

Comment: About users on M1 and M2: I want to prevent from signing in into one account from two machines. So when user is signing in into account, in which some user is logged, I want to sign out the first user that signed in.

Comment: The behavior you want to avoid can also be achieve in the same machine with different browsers, and i think is very hard to work around. The thing is the session is identified by a cookies kept by the browser, the browser will keep cookies unique, but different browser dont share that list , even less posible between computers. If you try it out with devise and gmail you will see you cant double login with the same browser/machine but you can with different browsers/machine. There is a possibility that you can reset the session of the user before login them in which is a posible work around.

Comment: This is exactly what I want! Machines were only shortcut of my minds:) Could you tell me how to achieve resetting the user session before login?